# Sending an input variable form a batch file to a powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I wanted to set up a file that would ask for which branch's server is going down and then email them accordingly to alert them of the restart. 
I have 2 variables, $server and $setTime. How do I get the the powershell script to read translate those variables into text?

Powershell script:

```
$MyEmail = "email@email.net"
$SMTP= "mail.email.net"
$To = "$server@email.net"
$Subject = "$server Server Restart"
$Body = "All,

We will be restarting the $server server at $setTime.
Printing and folder access wil be offline during the restart. 
The server will be offline for 5 minutes.

Helpdesk"

Start-Sleep 2

Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTP -DeliveryNotificationOption never
```

Batch File:

```
@echo off

set /p server = What server is being restarted?
set /p setTime = What time?

PowerShell.exe -Command c:\users\%username%\Desktop\dotComEmails\xServerIsDown.ps1 -server
```

Comment: Thank you for showing your code.  You're asking your question the right way.  +1, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, lose the spaces around the equal signs in your batch `set /P` commands.  Should be

```perl
set /P "server=What server is being restarted? "
set /P "setTime=What time? "
```

...etc.

To answer your question, within your PowerShell script, you can refer to these variables within the `env` scope -- `$env:server` and `$env:setTime`.

```perl
$Body = @"
All,

We will be restarting the $env:server server at $env:setTime.
Printing and folder access will be offline during the restart. 
The server will be offline for 5 minutes.

Helpdesk
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file needs to look like this:

```
@echo off

set /p server=What server is being restarted?
set /p setTime=What time?

PowerShell.exe "& 'c:\users\%username%\Desktop\dotComEmails\xServerIsDown.ps1' '%server%' '%setTime%'"
```

**Please note** that if you put a space before the = sign in the SET commands, it will break!

Then in the PowerShell script, you can assign those argument values to variables.  Shortest, sweetest way is:

```
$server = $args[0]
$time = $args[1]
```